# Why and How the plot between the real and imaginary component of an analytic signal is in the form of an ellipse pattern?

Tags: discrete-signals, analytic-signal

Why and How the plot between the real and imaginary component of an analytic signal is in the form of an ellipse pattern ? How does the ellipse pattern varies with the variation in real and imaginary components of an analytic signal ? Can you share a research paper (journal or conference paper) to study more about it ? Because I am also working in this area of research.

Answer (score 2):

The real and imaginary components of an analytic signal are not in an ellipse pattern. As is well established in introductory DSP books, the real and imaginary components of the analytic signal are related by the Hilbert transform, given as:

$$x_a(t) = x(t)+\hat{x}(t)$$

Where

$x_a(t)$ is the analytic signal representation for $x(t)$, which is typically but not necessarily real.

$\hat{x}(t)$ is the Hilbert transform of $x(t)$.

Consider the simplest analytic signal given as:

$$e^{j\omega t} = \cos(\omega t) + j\sin(\omega t)$$

Where $\cos(\omega t)$ is the real waveform with Hilbert Transform as $\sin(\omega t)$. $e^{j\omega t}$ is therefore the analytic signal representation of $\cos(\omega t)$.  This is always the case, the real component of the analytic waveform is the original real signal, and the imaginary component of the analytic waveform is the Hilbert Transform of the original real signal. This is how they are related.

Further, the analytic signal has no negative frequency components. If the real and imaginary components of a signal were related as an ellipse, we would have the relationship:

$$y(t)= a\cos(\omega t) + j b\sin(\omega t)$$

$$= \frac{a}{2}(e^{j\omega t}+e^{-j\omega t})+j\frac{b}{2}(je^{j\omega t}-je^{-j\omega t})$$

$$= \frac{a}{2}(e^{j\omega t}+e^{-j\omega t})+\frac{b}{2}(-e^{j\omega t}+e^{-j\omega t})$$

$$=\frac{a-b}{2}e^{j\omega t} + \frac{a+b}{2}e^{-j\omega t}$$

which as shown above has a negative frequency component for all cases other than $b=-a$, so it cannot be an analytic signal. (“Positive” frequencies are a positive exponent for  the exponential frequency representation, as in $e^{j\omega t}$ and “negative” frequencies are a negative exponent as in $e^{j \omega t}$, therefore an analytic signal can only be expressed with positive exponents of exponential frequencies.)

Comment: Can you share a research paper (journal or conference paper) for studying more about it.

Comment: This should help you: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_signal. It’s a basic signal processing concept and not a subject of ongoing research, well covered in any of the classic text books on signal processing - so I don’t think you’ll find a journal or conference paper that explains it. But did my response above help you?